# How to delete an empty array in php

Tags: php, laravel

I am dealing with arrays in php. And have an empty array problem like below:

**In Controller :**

```
        $name = [];
        if (!empty($request->mobile)) { 
            $name['mobile'] = $request->mobile;
        }
        dd($name);

        //Result :

        array(1) {
            ["mobile"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              array(2) {
                ["link"]=>
                string(4) "adc.co"
                ["image"]=>
                string(36) "a1119e740c170e5a29bf2fd4deff8c83.png"
              }
              [1]=>
              array(0) {
              }
            }
          }
```

Is there a way for me to remove the empty array inside `$name` . I want to clear this array:

```
[1]=>
   array(0) {
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: `unset($name['mobile'][1]);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't want to `unset` the value statically..here is an array i just gave an example.in fact it has many more arrays

Comment: you can also just skip it when processing `foreach ($name['mobile'] as $mobile) { if ($mobile) {......} /*skipping any empty array */ }`

Comment: Well it may be more productive to show us the actual array structure so we can write you a little loop to find empty arrays and remove them

Comment: have a look at function array_filter, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use PHP [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove any empty values like `null, 0, ''`

```
print_r(array_filter($name));
```

or

you can use [laravel helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers) as you have not mentioned the laravel version hope you're using the latest one(8.x).

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$filtered = Arr::where($name, function ($value, $key) {
    return !empty($value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Pragnesh Chauhan